# how to display spinner when data is being fetched from cloud firestore in vuejs?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

i'm working on firebase and vuejs with vuex as well. so in onauthStateChanged() method i try to get all the data form posts collection. its takes some time to display, In meanwhile i want to display spinner that specifies the user where some something is being loading.

i tried and its works cool, but the problem with code is

```
  <loadingSpinner v-if="loading"></loadingSpinner>
                <div v-if="posts.length">
                    <div v-for="post in posts" v-bind:key=post.id class="post">
                        <h5>{{ post.userName }}</h5>
                        <span>{{ post.createdOn | formatDate }}</span>
                        <p>{{ post.content | trimLength }}</p>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a @click="openCommentModal(post)">comments {{ post.comments }}</a></li>
                            <li><a @click="likePost(post.id, post.likes)">likes {{ post.likes }}</a></li>
                            <li><a @click="viewPost(post)">view full post</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div v-else>
                    <p class="no-results">There are currently no posts</p>
                </div>
```

Spinner component responsible for spin animation:

```
<loadingSpinner v-if="loading"></loadingSpinner>
```

And the below html code is for displaying data from firebase

Where posts and loading variables are the computed properties from vuex state

problem is when is reload the page, spinner showing along the

```
<div v-else>
     <p class="no-results">There are currently no posts</p>
</div>
```

I want to restrict the v-else condition when the spinner is being loaded.

By the way, the loading computed properties is a boolean that reacts based on onAuthstateChanged() firebase method

this is my entire vuex store file :

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
const fb = require('./firebaseConfig.js')

Vue.use(Vuex)

// handle page reload
fb.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
        store.commit('setCurrentUser', user)
        store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')

        fb.usersCollection.doc(user.uid).onSnapshot(doc => {
            store.commit('setUserProfile', doc.data())
        })

        // realtime updates from our posts collection
        fb.postsCollection.orderBy('createdOn', 'desc').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
            // check if created by currentUser
            let createdByCurrentUser
            if (querySnapshot.docs.length) {
                createdByCurrentUser = store.state.currentUser.uid == querySnapshot.docChanges[0].doc.data().userId ? true : false
            }

            // add new posts to hiddenPosts array after initial load
            if (querySnapshot.docChanges.length !== querySnapshot.docs.length
                && querySnapshot.docChanges[0].type == 'added' && !createdByCurrentUser) {

                let post = querySnapshot.docChanges[0].doc.data()
                post.id = querySnapshot.docChanges[0].doc.id

                store.commit('setHiddenPosts', post)
            } else {
                store.commit('setLoading', true)
                let postsArray = []
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    let post = doc.data()
                    post.id = doc.id
                    postsArray.push(post)
                })     
                store.commit('setPosts', postsArray)
                store.commit('setLoading', false)
            }
        })
    }
})

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        currentUser: null,
        userProfile: {},
        posts: [],
        hiddenPosts: [],
        loading: true
    },
    actions: {
        clearData({ commit }) {
            commit('setCurrentUser', null)
            commit('setUserProfile', {})
            commit('setPosts', null)
            commit('setHiddenPosts', null)
        },
        fetchUserProfile({ commit, state }) {
            fb.usersCollection.doc(state.currentUser.uid).get().then(res => {
                commit('setUserProfile', res.data())
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        },
        updateProfile({ commit, state }, data) {
            let name = data.name
            let title = data.title

            fb.usersCollection.doc(state.currentUser.uid).update({ name, title }).then(user => {
                // update all posts by user to reflect new name
                fb.postsCollection.where('userId', '==', state.currentUser.uid).get().then(docs => {
                    docs.forEach(doc => {
                        fb.postsCollection.doc(doc.id).update({
                            userName: name
                        })
                    })
                })
                // update all comments by user to reflect new name
                fb.commentsCollection.where('userId', '==', state.currentUser.uid).get().then(docs => {
                    docs.forEach(doc => {
                        fb.commentsCollection.doc(doc.id).update({
                            userName: name
                        })
                    })
                })
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        setLoading(state, payload){
            state.loading = payload
        },
        setCurrentUser(state, val) {
            state.currentUser = val
            // console.log(val)
        },
        setUserProfile(state, val) {
            state.userProfile = val
            // console.log(val)
        },
        setPosts(state, val) {
            if (val) {
                state.posts = val
            } else {
                state.posts = []
            }
        },
        setHiddenPosts(state, val) {
            if (val) {
                // make sure not to add duplicates
                if (!state.hiddenPosts.some(x => x.id === val.id)) {
                    state.hiddenPosts.unshift(val)
                }
            } else {
                state.hiddenPosts = []
            }
        }
    },
})
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You should share your entire vuex code + your entire component code, because to solve your problem you have to "drive"/control the spinner display from the asynchronous tasks. In other words, when you start querying you show the spinner and as soon the promise from the Firebase requests is resolved you hide the spinner.

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: I think there is everything you need, in your code (which comes from this tutorial https://savvyapps.com/blog/definitive-guide-building-web-app-vuejs-firebase), to fulfill you needs: You should use the `store.commit('setLoading', true)` and `store.commit('setLoading', false)`to control the spinner. I would kindly suggest you study this tutorial in detail and try to adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would tweak your `v-if/v-else` logic at bit.

```
<loadingSpinner v-if="loading" />
<div v-else-if="posts.length"></div>
<div v-else>
    <p class="no-results">There are currently no posts</p>
</div>
```

The difference is `v-else-if` on `posts.length`, instead of `v-if`. This way, there are 3 distinct states.

1. Loading, show spinner.
2. Not loading, show posts.
3. Not loading, there are no posts, show no results.